# How do I get the data of one row of a Structured Streaming Dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka, discretization

I have a Kafka broker with a topic connected to Spark Structured Streaming. My topic sends data to my streaming dataframe, and I'd like to get information on each row for this topic (because I need to compare each row with another database).

If I could transform my batches into an RDD I could get each row easily.
I also saw something about DStreams but I don't know if with the last version f spark it still works.

Is DStream the answer to my problem or if there is any other solution to get my data row by row?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use forEachBatch and forEachPartition to get RDDs from your streaming dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data in spark streaming from kafka and write your custom row comparison in foreach writer of spark streaming
.
eg.

```
streamingDatasetOfString.writeStream.foreach(
```

new ForeachWriter[String] {

```
def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
  // Open connection
}

def process(record: String): Unit = {
  // Write string to connection
}

def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
  // Close the connection
}}).start()
```

`
This is supported in python,scala,java since spark 2.4